# mod_rewrite RewriteRule external domain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to rewrite all urls like domain1.com/site to domain2.com and want view the content in domain2.com but with the urls of domain1.com

I try this code in .htaccess file in domain1.com root directory:

```
RewriteRule ^sito http://mariomaffei.it/$1 [P]
```

but I can't see correctly webpages

I'm testing it on this site: officinacm.it/sito
Can anybody help me?

Comment: What do you mean by _with the urls of domain1.com_?

Comment: I would navigate into mariomaffei.it but the initial part of the url must be officinacm.it/sito
Is it possible to do this with mod_rewrite (but without redirection!)

Comment: You can do this using mod_proxy, like what you have by using the `P` flag. If it's not proxying, then you don't have mod_proxy loaded.